# SQL procedure group by parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, group-by

I want to use group by functionality with dynamic value.

Ex:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getEmpStats (@COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DUPLICATE_COUNTS INT

    BEGIN
        SELECT @DUPLICATE_COUNTS = SUM(DUP_COUNTS)
        FROM 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS DUP_COUNTS
             FROM emp
             GROUP BY @COLUMN_NAME) AS A

        -------------------
    END
END
```

When I code like this I get the error  == >

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Yip, dynamic SQL.

Comment: @marc_s your rep is the number of the devil!

Comment: @DaleK Sorry, I didn't aware of that. I marked correct answers for my previous questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be very careful with this type of code as it is prone to SQL injection.

Always use `QUOTENAME` on identifiers. And if the column name is coming from user code then verify it.

Because `@DUPLICATE_COUNTS` is not in scope in the dynamic part, you need to re-declare it as an `OUTPUT` parameter.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE getEmpStats (@COLUMN_NAME varchar(20))
AS

DECLARE @DUPLICATE_COUNTS int;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'

        SELECT @DUPLICATE_COUNTS = SUM(DUP_COUNTS)
        FROM 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS DUP_COUNTS
             FROM emp
             GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + N') AS A;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@DUPLICATE_COUNTS int OUTPUT', @DUPLICATE_COUNTS = @DUPLICATE_COUNTS

GO
```

To verify the column name, use this code:

```sql
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.name = @COLUMN_NAME AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'emp')
    ))
    THROW 50000, 'Non existent column', 0;
```

Comment: I just wanted to get the duplicate row count by passing the column name.
As an example, the table contains two columns as NAME and AGE.The values are "{NAME:Sunil,AGE:10},{NAME:Kamal,AGE:10},{NAME:Steve,AGE:20},{NAME:Smith,AGE:20},{NAME:Jane,AGE:30}" .Here I want to pass the column name AGE as the parameter and check the total duplicate count. So if we write the code SELECT COUNT(*) AS DUP_COUNT FROM emp GROUP BY AGE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 I will get the answer as { DUP_COUNT: 2},{ DUP_COUNT: 2}. I want the answer as 4.I want the total number of rows that have been duplicated. (2+2)

Comment: Passing parameters like this worked perfectly.Thanks a lot